# I need help in setting random time between 15s to 300s using math.round function

Tags: javascript, time

I've set up a popup that will automatically appear at 7000ms.

The original code is

```
function run_heard_open_<?php echo $val->id; ?>() {
    if (heardClick<?php echo $val->id; ?> != 1){
    var open_heard = 7000; 
    setTimeout(function(){
          jQuery('#mwp-heard-<?php echo $val->id; ?>').animate({opacity: 1, right: '3%'}, 400); 
          var rand_heard_name = Math.floor(Math.random() * heard_name_<?php echo $val->id; ?>.length);
      var rand_heard_city = Math.floor(Math.random() * heard_city_<?php echo $val->id; ?>.length);
      var rand_heard_number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (<?php echo $val->amount_min;?> - <?php echo $val->amount_max;?>)) + <?php echo $val->amount_max;?>;
      var heard_text = "<?php echo $val->herd_text; ?>";
      var heard_text_name = heard_text.replace("[name]", heard_name_<?php echo $val->id; ?>[rand_heard_name]);
      var heard_text_city = heard_text_name.replace("[city]", heard_city_<?php echo $val->id; ?>[rand_heard_city]);
      var heard_text_new = heard_text_city.replace("[amount]", rand_heard_number);
      jQuery('#mwp-heard-text-<?php echo $val->id; ?>').html(heard_text_new);
      run_heard_close_<?php echo $val->id; ?>();
      }, open_heard); 
      }
}
```

I've changed the code to this

```
 var open_heard = Math.round(Math.random() * (3000 - 500)) + 500;
```

It however does not seem to work. Where did I do wrong? Also I would like the pop up to run as a loop. Where can I insert the function?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: I absolutely hate when people do not understand the random formula and stick to that silly syntax that someone posted. Sure it works, its awesome but UNDERSTANDING what it does is even better.... `Math.random()` gives you a random decimal from 0 to 1, not including 1. So technically 0 to 0.99999999. Multiply this by a proper amount, round it, floor it, do whatever you want with it. Then, if needed, add the minimum to it, you are done

Comment: Thankyou for your critic. So, does it mean adding this `var open_heard = Math.round(Math.random() * (300000 - 15000)) + 15000;` will generate time in between 15s - 300s ??? Sorry as I'm new to coding... I'm still learning on it.

Comment: It does, but putting 300000-15000 in there and adding series of brackets is unnecessary. `Math.floor(Math.random() * 275001) + 15000` is the more appropriate, but it makes no goddamn difference, result is the same, its just a trigger for my OCD. This way you get a more precise solution, however mathematically speaking it is less correct in a chance per integer. There is no way to make it more precise though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by Alexandru you have a syntax error with your var open_heard. Also, if you want the code to run on a loop then you should use setInterval. If you want to have it run only once, then you should use setTimeout.

```js
//Setting min to 15s and max to 300s
var open_heard = Math.round(Math.random() * (300000 - 15000)) + 15000;
setInterval(function(){alert(open_heard)},open_heard);
```

Comment: Thankyou for the code. Have a question, I have multiple element ID =  _#mwp-heard-1 #mwp-heard-2 #mwp-heard-3_ (pop up groups) How do I group them into different `var open_heard` based on different ID ?

Comment: @Desmond If you want to do different open_heard (or random cycle times) for each pop-up, your easiest solution is to just make a new random time for each individual pop-up.

Comment: Yeah, I was about to do so but I'm not sure of how. How to link the different open_heard to the different element ID (#mwp-heard-1; #mwp-heard-2; #mwp-heard-3? sorry I'm new to PHP.

Comment: @Desmond you could potentially make an array of the open_heard values that matches to the val so heard[<?php echo $val->] = open_heard_<?php echo $val->